# Difference between determining a transformation is linear when given vector components not points?

Tags: linear-algebra

I understand how to do $T(x,y,z) = (x+2,y-3,z)$

but get confused when given a vector ex. $T(v) = (v\cdot w,v\cdot 2w,v\cdot3w)$

both are in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Specifically, how can I prove the above transformation is linear?

Comment: I'm sorry you're confused.  What is your question?

Comment: how do I test if this transformation is linear? I would normally use the two requirements of a linear equation and manipulate the equations to prove that they hold. I can't figure out how when given vectors and a transformation that included two vectors multiplied

Comment: The comment belongs in the body of your question.

Comment: You do exactly the same thing.  Here, you need to use the properties of the dot product.  Perhaps you haven't realized that $w$ is a constant vector.  Give it a try, and if you run into trouble, edit the question to show precisely where you are having difficulty.

Comment: That answer belongs in the answer section.

Comment: What is the meaning of this question?

Comment: Determine if T(v)=(v⋅w,v⋅2w,v⋅3w) is linear

Comment: You need to check that $T(v+\lambda v')=T(v)+\lambda T(v')$ for any $v,v'\in E$ and $\lambda \in k$, if you are working in the $k$-vector space $E$.

Comment: @shroomyshroomy Okay.  I agree that too many comments are really answers, so that too many question show as not having been answered.

Answer (score 1):

You do exactly the same thing. Here, you need to use the properties of the dot product. Perhaps you haven't realized that w is a constant vector. Give it a try, and if you run into trouble, edit the question to show precisely where you are having difficulty.